# How to resolve a different promise in each case of a switch block and pass their results to the same function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Suppose that I want to execute different promise chains in the various `case` blocks of a `switch` block, and ultimately return the result to the client via `res.end()`, like this:

```
app.post('/endpoint',function(req,res){
    var reqValue=req.body.value;
    var resValue="initial value";
    switch(reqValue){
         case 'a':
             someObj.action_a()
             .then(result=>{
                 resValue=result.id;
             });
             break;
         case 'b':
             someObj.action_b()
             .then(result=>{
                 resValue=result.id;
             });
             break;
         default:
             resValue="default";
    }
    doSomethingElse();
    res.end(resValue);
});
```

What ends up happening is that `resValue` is returned as `"initial value"`, which makes sense because the asynchronous functions in the `case` blocks aren't updating `resValue` before execution reaches `res.end()`.  I could move the post-`switch` code into the promise resolutions like this:

```
         case 'a':
             someObj.action_a()
             .then(result=>{
                 resValue=result.id;
                 doSomethingElse();
                 res.end(resValue);
             });
             break;
         case 'b':
             someObj.action_b()
             .then(result=>{
                 resValue=result.id;
                 doSomethingElse();
                 res.end(resValue);
             });
             break;
         default:
             resValue="default";
             doSomethingElse();
             res.end(resValue);
```

but then this is duplicating code and therefore more challenging to maintain.  Is there a better way to have these `switch`-mediated promises all end up at the same `res.end()`?

Comment: `treat this block of code as synchronous` - dangerous way to treat asynchronous code - how about *use async await* without the rest :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a single variable to hold a promise of the required resValue like so

```
app.post('/endpoint',function(req,res){
    let reqValue=req.body.value;
    let p;
    switch(reqValue){
         case 'a':
             p = someObj.action_a().then(result => result.id);
             break;
         case 'b':
             p = someObj.action_b().then(result => result.id);
             break;
         default:
             // p has to be a promise, so make it one
             p = Promise.resolve("default");
    }
    p.then(resValue => {
        doSomethingElse();
        res.end(resValue);
    });
});
```

or using modern javascript, use async/await

```
app.post('/endpoint',async function(req,res){
    let reqValue=req.body.value;
    let resValue="initial value";
    switch(reqValue){
         case 'a':
             resValue = await someObj.action_a().then(result => result.id);
             break;
         case 'b':
             resValue = await someObj.action_b().then(result => result.id);
             break;
         default:
             resValue = "default";
    }
    doSomethingElse();
    res.end(resValue);
});
```

Comment: that is why copy/paste is a bad thing :p

Comment: I don't follow your accusation @vdegenne - of course I copy/pasted and then **changed** the OP's code

Answer (score 3):

If you can use new features of JavaScript I'd recommend `async` and `await` because they are easy to read and to use, your code would change to this :

```
let resValue = "default";
switch (reqValue) {
  case 'a':
    resValue = (await someObj.action_a()).id;
    break;
  case 'b':
    resValue = (await someObj.action_b()).id;
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
doSomethingElse();
res.end(resValue);
```

Comment: you can't just use `await` like that - i.e. you forgot to show that the enclosing function needs to be `async` :p ... `If you can use new features of JavaScript` - OP uses arrow functions, pretty safe bet :p

Comment: @JaromandaX intentionally omitted ! because if he is to use this modern syntax of JS he would certainly run into other problems that he needs to learn from himself. Needless to say I was just trying to direct him in a solution he could be interested in :p

Comment: @JaromandaX `OP uses arrow functions, pretty safe bet :p` - `async` and `await` are ES2017, arrow functions are ES2015. That's not a very safe bet.

Comment: @vdegenne `resValue = (await someObj.action_a()).id;` would mirror the intent in the question. Currently, you're assigning `result` instead of `result.id`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - not many people would be using an environment that has one and not the other - though, there are some that hang on to particularly old nodejs, so I guess it's a fair point

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, instead, you could create a general function that returns data based on the action type it's given, and have the `switch` there, and use a simple async/await in your main function just to await the result that

```js
// Made up function that switches action
// based on the type (in this case the timer on the
// setTimeout)
function doAction(type) {
  let time;
  switch(type) {
    case 'a': time = 1000; break;
    case 'b': time = 2000; break;
    case 'c': time = 300; break;
  }
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ id: `${type}1` }), time);
  });
}

async function main(type) {
  try {

    // Pass in the type to the doAction function,
    // let that decide what to do, and await the promise
    // to resolve
    const result = await doAction(type);

    // Then just console.log or res.send the result 
    const resValue = result.id;
    console.log(resValue);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

main('b');
main('a');
main('c');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option if you can't use `async/await` and instead must stick to `Promises` (However, the nested ternaries could get unsightly if you have a lot of cases; read on for a different idea):

```
app.post('/endpoint', function(req, res) {
  const reqValue = req.body.value;
  (reqValue === 'a'
    ? someObj.action_a().then(({id}) => id)
    : reqValue === 'b'
      ? someObj.action_b.then(({id}) => id)
      : Promise.resolve('default'))
        .then(resValue => {
          doSomethingElse();
          res.end(resValue);
        });
});
```

Instead, suppose you store your actions in an `Object`:

```
const actions = {
  a: () => someObj.action_a();
  b: () => someObj.action_b();
  // ...
  n: () => someObj.action_n();
};

app.post('endpoint', function(req, res) {
  const action = actions[req.body.value];
  (action && action().then(({id}) => id) || Promise.resolve('default'))
    .then(resValue => {
      doSomethingElse();
      res.end(resValue);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`Promise.all` is a very handy tool for keeping tracking of all sub-promises tasks

```js
const jobqQeue = [];

switch(...) {
  case: '...': {
    jobqQeue.push(
      subPromise()
    );
  }
  case: '...': {
    jobqQeue.push(
      subPromise2()
    );
  }
  default: {
    jobqQeue.push(
      defaultOpPromise();
    );
  }
}

Promise.all(jobqQeue)
.then(results => {
  ...
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: there's no reason to have an array of promises when there can only ever be one :p